# New operating system for a Dell Dimension XPS Gen 2

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-xp, drivers, windows-vista

Neighbor was running Windows XP Home till last week, but when the computer became too sluggish, he backed up his data and formatted it. He tried installing 
Windows 7 Home 32 bit(he got a retail copy), but the installation DVD was not able to recognize the hard drive of Dell Dimension XPS Gen 2 which was  WDC WD1200JD-75GBB0 so now
the computer is without a operating system. He bought it in March 2004 so it is old, but he feels the hardware is working so by installing a operating system he can use it for few more years.

1. What operating system can be installed on this computer? The Dell's website mentions only Windows XP which is tested for that model.
2. Can you get the drivers for the hard drive which is WDC WD1200JD-75GBB0 and embed it with the Windows 7 32 bit installation DVD to see if the Windows 7 installation can work?
3. Or, will Windows Vista be a better option? I understand it is difficult to find a retail copy.

Dell Dimension XPS Gen 2 had only had one hard drive. But, it had SATA/RAID enabled in the BIOS which I turned off after which the install went smoothly. **Thanks to all who responded.**

Comment: What drivers exactly do you feel they need to get?  You have no provided enough information to identify the reason this person is unable to install Windows 7 on a machine that has the ability to run it.

Comment: The WDC WD1200JD is a regular SATA drive. Which means that no drivers are needed for the drive at all. However you do need drivers for the onboard SATA **controller**.

Comment: Thanks Ramhound, Windows 7 DVD cannot detect the hard drive so it is missing the drivers for the onboard SATA controller.

Comment: Thanks Hennes, how do I get the drivers for the onboard SATA controller? Dell website is not helpful for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dell Dimension XPS Gen 2 had only had one hard drive. But, it had SATA/RAID enabled in the BIOS which I turned off after which the install went smoothly.  In other words, I turned it to regular AHCI mode.

Comment: This is probably because the fake RAID mode is not about RAID but also allows more feature. So Dell turns this on even with one drive. Which means you need to load the right drivers during installation to get it to work **or** turn it to regular AHCI mode. Reading your answer you did the last. Maybe you could also explicitly mention that?

Answer (score 0):

If the computer meets the Windows 7 system requirements, it should be able to install.

If the hard drive wasn't detected by the installation, I'd check the BIOS to see it the hard drive is detected there. If it is, I'd boot to something like GParted or even a Linux Live CD to see if they see the hard drive.

If it isn't detected in BIOS, the hard drive is bad.

Comment: Thanks, Ultimate Boot CD can see the hard drive. But, the onboard SATA controller needed by the hard drive was not present in the Windows 7 install disc so it likely did not detect the hard drive.